# Connect to TOR serivce to upload files FTP/SFTP

Tags: onion-services, socks

I would like to upload some files to my `.onion` website over FTP/SFTP securely however I cannot figure how to connect. Any help?

I have added the following to `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ftp-service/
HiddenServicePort 21 127.0.0.1:21
HiddenServicePort 2000
```

I also added the SOCKS5 proxy `127.0.0.1:9150` to my Filezilla Connection settings.

After I paste my `.onion` link in the host field in Filezilla I get the following log:

```
Connecting to MYONIONLINKHERE.onion through SOCKS5 proxy
Status:         Resolving address of 127.0.0.1
Status:         Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9150...
Status:         Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
Error:          Proxy request failed. Reply from proxy: Connection refused
Error:          Could not connect to server
```